# How to tell which planet is habitable in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

The Empire is still young and need to grow, fast.

Our admirals need to know which planet is habitable to plane our next domination move and send colony ships.

Currently, they are iterating each planet (50~60 planets), remembering which one is habitable, this is a tedious work.

Is there a better way to tell which planet is habitable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you turn on the full details option (checkmark in the lower right-hand corner of the screen), then any system with potentially habitable worlds will have a world-shaped icon next to it on the galaxy map.

Red worlds can't be colonized yet due to a lack of technology. Yellow and green worlds can be colonized, with green worlds having better habitability. I think the threshold for green is 70%. This is calculated based on the best rating among all the races in your empire.

Hovering over the icon will give you a tooltip with details on which worlds are in the system and their habitability rating.

Comment: This one is a blessing - 10x a lot, I should have asked it long ago.

Comment: Just found out that if you hold the <ALT> key, the map is also filled with the desired information.

Comment: @ShloEmi I've seen you put "10x" in a number of comments here. What is that?

Comment: No idea why they don't enable full details by default, why would you not want it on?

Comment: @Carra The only time I ever turn it off is when I've pretty much colonized everything, just to reduce clutter. It seems like it really only gets rid of the planet icons, though. You definitely want it on at the start of the game.

Comment: @DCShannon, I think _10x_ is phonetic shorthand for _thanks._

Comment: @BraddSzonye Huh. That's probably it. But, if that's *phonetic* shorthand, then I'd be curious to hear how the person is pronouncing 'thanks'.

Answer (score 5):

You can only get basic info in the release version.  When the [Clarke Update](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-dev-diary-34-clarke-patch.936898/) gets released the new tooltip (linked below) for systems with habitable worlds will include better information, habitability rating, size, and world type.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/umRygrv.png]

Comment: Good to know, this is more like a comment than an answer Kexlox, care to add this good tip as a comment (again - 10x for the goodwill ).

Comment: This answer is useful for showing a screenshot. The green icon in the back is unchanged from the current version. That's the green world icon my answer references.